# Abelian category: Composition is linear

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

Context: Looking at the definition of an abelian category.

- $H=\text{Hom}(A,B)$ is an abelian group. I imagine this is just saying $f,g\in H$ then $(f+g)(a)=f(a)+g(a)$.
- What does it mean to say that the composition law of morphisms is linear? Are we asking for a map $\text{Hom}(A,B)\times \text{Hom}(B,C)\to \text{Hom}(A,C)$ and asking for this to be linear, in the sense that $$f\in \text{Hom}(A,B), g\in \text{Hom}(B,C),\quad g\circ f\in \text{Hom}(A,C),$$$$ g\circ f(a+b) =g\circ f(a)+g\circ f(b)$$ But does that not follow from simply having this composition, and that $\text{Hom}(A,C)$ is an abelian group?

Comment: What is $a+b$ here? You don't have an addition on $A$. What you want is $g\circ(f+h)=g\circ f+g\circ h$ and the like on the left.

Comment: Who is $a$ ? Don't forget that in category theory, objects need not be sets, and so $f(a)$ doesn't necessarily make sense

Comment: @A.Rod Thanks, you can post that as an answer if you wish.

Comment: @Max Good point Max, thanks.

Comment: @Max I like the phrasing "who" is $a$!

Comment: Note that this is actually a bilinearity condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the condition of *linear composition*.

When they say that composition in an abelian category is (bi)linear they actually mean that the map

$$\hom[B,C] \times \hom[A,B] \longrightarrow \hom[A,C]$$
$$(g,f) \mapsto g \circ f$$
is bilinear, that is for each $f,f_1,f_2 \in \hom[A,B]$ and $g,g_1,g_2 \in \hom[B,C]$ the equalities 
$$(g_1+g_2)\circ f = (g_1 \circ f) + (g_2 \circ f)$$
$$g \circ (f_1+f_2) = (g \circ f_1) + (g \circ f_2)$$
hold.

This condition differs from the one you wrote before, namely that for $f \in \hom[A,B]$ and $g \in \hom[B,C]$ then 
$$(g \circ f)(a+b)=(g \circ f)(a)+(g \circ f)(b)$$
for all $a,b \in A$, which instead means that $g \circ f$ is an homomorphism between additive objects (in order to be meaningful your equation require that both $A$ and $C$ have a $(+)$ defined on them, you have to be able to sum $a$ and $b$ and their image through $g \circ f$).

In particular since the equation depends on the objects $A$ and $C$ having an additive structure, the equation does not follows from the fact that the $\hom[X,Y]$'s are additive groups: just because you can add morphisms it doesn't mean that the objects have to be groups too.

If you need any additional detail or have any doubts please write in the comments.